# Unable to install LAMP (Linux, Apache, Mysql, PHP stack) on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, ip

I am trying to install LAMP server on my Ubuntu desktop. The problem I am facing is related to IP address of my laptop.

While Setting Global `ServerName` to Suppress Syntax Warnings, as the documentation says [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04#how-to-find-your-server-39-s-public-ip-address), when I am adding a `ServerName` directive, pointing to my server's public IP address in configuration file,                        `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

It says to add the following at the bottom of the config file

```
ServerName server_domain_or_IP
```

I added the IP address which the Google page displays (on searching my IP) and typed the URL `http://my_IP` But the default page was not displayed.

I think the IP which I used is wrong. As I am connected to my home wifi router and all the devices which are connected to the router has the same IP address.

Can anyone tell me how can I solve this problem? Which one is the correct IP to use and how can I find that IP address?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you are using is from Digital Ocean, where you can spin up virtual servers that have a publicly available IP address.  Your computer at home is not publicly available to the Internet.  When paying a company such as Digital Ocean, they are going to rent to you an IP address that is unique to the Internet and can be found by any browser in the world.

However, you can run your LAMP stack in your home as a local development server to learn about web development.  You will need to give your server a unique address within your network.  You can do this through your router, where you log on to your router, find your device and assign it a static IP address, such as `192.168.1.100`. You'll have to find the documentation for your router. This doesn't make it public, but rather makes it easy to find on other computers within your home network.

From there, you can get to your development server Apache by typing the IP address directly in your browser, without the `http://`, simply type `192.168.1.100` and if your LAMP stack is up and running should give you an initial Apache page.

There is a lot to learn, but take it one step at a time and you'll get there.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). The IP address you are using is not your server's public IP address, it is your router's public IP address.

Your server doesn't have a public IP address.

You need to listen on your server's LAN IP address and configure your router to perform port forwarding to your HTTP server on that IP.